# How can I redirect the contents of a file to the pastebinit command?

Tags: command-line, redirect, pastebin

Whenever I was to store something to show someone here, I run

```
command-with-output | pastebinit.
```

That returns the link to the paste online. For example:

```
echo sometext | pastebinit
```

gave me the link

[paste.ubuntu.com/8010000](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8010000)

Which I can share. How can I do this with a file - for example a log file. Surely I don't have to `open - > copy all - > open paste.ubuntu.com -> paste it`?

Comment: Is it a dupe? Different question, same answer.

Comment: yeah it is :D Yay 5 ahead of Oli >:D That one might be better changed to a more generic question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cat` is the command to do that:

```
cat filename | pastebinit
```

From `man cat`:

> cat - concatenate files and print on the standard output

```
    -A, --show-all
          equivalent to -vET
   -b, --number-nonblank
          number nonempty output lines
   -e     equivalent to -vE
   -E, --show-ends
          display $ at end of each line
   -n, --number
          number all output lines
   -s, --squeeze-blank
          suppress repeated empty output lines
   -t     equivalent to -vT
   -T, --show-tabs
          display TAB characters as ^I
   -v, --show-nonprinting
          use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB

   With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd personally use `cat` ([per Rinzwind's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/514550/449)) but there's also an `-i` flag:

```
pastebinit -i [filename]
```

---

From `man pastebinit`:

```
OPTIONS  
       -i [filename] Use filename for input
```